# vBulletin 5.0 global.php

Tags: php, vbulletin

Does anyone know how to include global.php in vbulletin 5 on an external page (non-vb)? My previous 4.0 code doesnt work:

```
$curdir = getcwd();
chdir('chat/');
require_once('core/global.php');
chdir ($curdir);
```

I now get "Accessed Denied."

Answer (score 1):

This one did the trick for me.

```
if (!defined('VB_ENTRY')) {
    define('VB_ENTRY', 1);
}

define('VB_AREA', 'Forum');

require_once('core/includes/init.php');
require 'core/global.php';
```